# python copytree slower than bash rsync

Tags: python, rsync, copytree

I try to write a python script to backup a network folder nearly 400 GB.

This is my python code :

```
     shutil.copytree(source_folder, current_backup)
```

The script stops after 7 hours without any error.
So I tried

```
    cmd = "rsync -a " + source_folder + " " +  current_backup
    os.system(cmd);
```

The scrpt finished after 6 hours. It is alocal network
But my question is :
Why is the python method so extrem slower or stopps.
Or is there a better way ?
After coping the files and folders I want to create a zip archive.
I will try to do this in one step

Comment: What's wrong about using `rsync` ? Why not zipping first and copy the zip-file afterwards (which should improve runtime) ?

Comment: Thanks for your idea. There is not enough space on the source system to save a zipped copy.  The question is if there exists a faster way